# Duplicate declaration in current scope - no duplicate anywhere

Tags: excel, vba, variables, integer

i am having a major problem that i cannot figure out
it is telling me i have a duplicate declaration....but i do not!
I even changed the variable to something else and it still says it.
Unfortunately my code is crazy long so i am only pasting the part that gives me the error.
On the second line (dim c as integer) is where i get the error
even if i change C to D, i still get the error, not sure how that is even possible.
I have done a search, and the search shows that DIM C is the only one in my whole project!!!!!

Any thoughts, please i am crazy desperate....300 hours of coding for it to fail on a last tiny simple command.

I really really appreciate it!

```
Dim Msg As String
Dim C As Integer
Dim PrinterName As String

C = 1

On Error GoTo MakePDFError:

ResumePrinting:
If C < 10 Then
    PrinterName = "Verdun_Office on Ne0" & C & ":"
Else
    PrinterName = "Verdun_Office on Ne" & C & ":"
End If

Application.ActivePrinter = PrinterName
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=qty, ActivePrinter:= _
"Verdun_Office on Ne01:", collate:=True

 Worksheets("invoice excel").Activate
 Application.ActivePrinter = PrinterName
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, ActivePrinter:= _
"Verdun_Office on Ne01:", collate:=True

Exit Sub

MakePDFError:
C = C + 1
Resume ResumePrinting:
```

Comment: Have you tried making C something longer than a single character? I would suggest `Dim cValue` or something similar.

Comment: Change "C" to some string like "cVariable" and see if it happens. I'm guessing VB/Excel doesn't like the single character (perhaps it's an "embedded" variable in VB's code?).  Are you using `option explicit` (just curious)?  Generally, it's good practice anyways to use variable names that "make sense".  Looking at your code, we have no idea what `C` should ever be.  However, if you use perhaps `iRow` or `theRow`, etc. then it's more clear and also likely avoids this scope issue.

Comment: And I assume you haven't declared `C` globally either?  Do a search for that variable, but search the Module, not just Procedure.

Comment: remove Dim C as Integer and then right click C and select definition, it will take you to any other declarations.

Comment: This is one reason why you should give variables names that reflect what they are....Dim C is horrible practice.

Comment: And just because I think it's worth mentioning - it looks like you're using some `GoTo` lines elsewhere (because I see `ResumePrinting:`).  It's generally not the [best idea](http://xkcd.com/292/) to use `GoTo`, but instead write the code so you can do without it (one exception is using `On Error GoTo ErrHandler`).

Comment: So im far from a pro, but i did fix this by giving good variable names...so thanks a bunch .

Comment: But now i do have the problem with the resume printing....how do i get it to continue with the rest of my procedure once it has printed the sheet on the appropriate port. Right now it works, but after this i tell it to close the workbook and save but it is as if it just stops before getting to that step

Answer (score 3):

This happend to me today, my problem was I Dim de variable after calling it (not Dim still)

Example

```
Sub Dim_Duplicate()
   VarD=23
   'a lot of code here, so you not remember use the VarD before
   Dim VarD as Integer
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely due to your variable's name `C`.  As noted in the comments, best practice for variables (in VB, and programming in general) is to use a name that makes some sense to the user.  `C` tells us nothing.  It looks like you're using that to store a row value, so why not use `xRow` or `iRow` (note: Don't use `Row` since that's a special word within VB)?

Double check that `C` isn't declared Globally, and change it (and all instances, see @Nathan_Sav's suggestion in the comments) to something else, such as `iRow`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because the block of Dim statements was too low down in the procedure.
I moved them to the top and all was fine. I had NOT invoked the variable before the Dim statement. It just didn't like not getting the attention it wanted near the top of the subroutine! They are touchy these Dim statements.